# How to sum my incoming value from database (mysql) and how to fetch in my dashboard..?

Tags: php, mysql

Database name : newapp
table name    : customerorder
column name   : advance.

Subject : i want to fetch total (sum) advance amount. how can i do this ..? someone help me please.??

database connection is done. other query is working properly i required this one please
xampp version is latest.

Comment: Paste your code so that we can debug it.

Comment: i have no idea about this query dear

Comment: I have answered query please try it.

Comment: your query does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

This will work,you need to use  an alias for your SUM.

eg. `SELECT SUM(field) as 'something' FROM table_name`

this will make it easy for you to  be able to fetch the result normally by accessing the first result row's `$row['something']`

```
<?php
//YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION AND DB SELECTION
$sql = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`advance`) as `advanceAmount` FROM customerorder");

$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['advanceAmount'];
?>
```

For a specific user :

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`advance`) as `advanceAmount` FROM customerorder WHERE customerName='David'");
$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['advanceAmount'];
```

Or you may need to use customerID for a specific specif customer.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\TotalFinalweb\public\index.php on line 59

Comment: <?php
$server="localhost";
$username="root";
$pswrd="";
$db="atalapp";

$con=new mysqli ($server, $username, $pswrd, $db);
if($con->connect_error)
{
 die("Error :".connect_error);
}
else
{
 echo"Connection Connected <br>";
}

?>

Comment: Thank you. Now run :) :) :) God Bless you always

Comment: Cool, you can simple upvote and accept the answer so it can be closed

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
 $add="SELECT sum(field_name) FROM table_name";
   $total = mysqli_query($add);
    echo $total;
```

Comment: mysql api has been deprecated years ago and has been removed from php 7.0. Why are you suggesting its use?

Comment: Connection Connected 

Deprecated :  mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
C:\xampp\htdocs\TotalFinalweb\public\index.php  on line  49

Comment: you sdhuld try mysqli insted mysql.

Comment: use Mysqli Query structure now my mysql is closed for current version. this query just to get idea about sum.

Comment: Dear Dee_wab

can you please help me ?

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.